# Check for category issue

Tags: php, mysql

I have a problem with SQL .. For example, I have link http://www.site.com/single_video.php?id=96&kategorija=fails

And in that page there are two columns, one for show that video, and other for related videos..
But if user adds ' in link it will show nothing in column "related videos".. So I was trying to filter out "valid" categories.. But somehow it's not working..
Here's my code...

```
<?php
include 'includes/connect_video_index.php';
mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8"); //recimo bazi da postoje čak i hrvatska slova :D 
$result1 = mysql_query('SELECT * 
                          FROM video 
                         WHERE id!="'.$id1.'" 
                           AND kategorija="'.$escaped_cat.'" 
                      ORDER BY RAND() 
                         LIMIT 10', $con1);
while ($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($result1)){
    $kat = $_GET['kategorija'];
    $kategorija = mysql_real_escape_string($kat);
    if ($kategorija == $row1['kategorija']){
        echo 'This category exists'; //this part is working
    } else {
        //this part doesn't works when I enter blah blah, or whatever :S
        echo "This category doesnt' exist"; 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you type, 'somethingThatCantBeFound', no row is found, and the while loop makes... 0 iteration. Which means you can't reach the if statement. If `$escaped_cat` and `$kategorija` are the same, I mean. Are they ?

If you want to know if a category <strike>exists</strike> has videos, you can do this:

```
SELECT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM video WHERE kategorija = 'some category')
```

Comment: So how can I fix that? :D

Comment: Yeah, they are the same

Comment: Then why use 2 variables? That's confusing, you should fix that first.

Comment: I just Want to see if category exists, and if not type category doesnt' exists

Comment: see my second update. Regarding the injections, I don't see any vulnerability, but if you're worried about security, you probably shouldn't use the old Mysql extension: it is deprecated. You should use mysqli or PDO instead.